# android:exported be defined when intent filters are present

Tags: android

I am a beginner in programming and I am trying to understand more
I downloaded an open source app and am trying to make some modifications as a form of training
But when I set minsdk 31
The app no ​​longer works I checked after the lessons and instructions
I have to edit the mainfest file
I made some changes but I don't know if they are enough

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="org.schabi.newpipe"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:banner="@mipmap/newpipe_tv_banner"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/OpeningTheme"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".player.PlayerService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".player.PlayQueueActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_play_queue"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />

        <activity
            android:name=".settings.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings" />

        <activity
            android:name=".about.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" />

        <service android:name=".local.subscription.services.SubscriptionsImportService" />
        <service android:name=".local.subscription.services.SubscriptionsExportService" />
        <service android:name=".local.feed.service.FeedLoadService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PanicResponderActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="info.guardianproject.panic.action.TRIGGER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ExitActivity"
            android:label="@string/general_error"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
        <activity android:name=".error.ErrorActivity" />

        <!-- giga get related -->
        <activity
            android:name=".download.DownloadActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />

        <service android:name="us.shandian.giga.service.DownloadManagerService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".util.FilePickerActivityHelper"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FilePickerThemeDark"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".error.ReCaptchaActivity"
            android:label="@string/recaptcha" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/nnf_provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".RouterActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/preferred_open_action_share_menu_title"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/RouterActivityThemeDark"
            android:exported="true">

            <!-- Youtube filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="youtube.com" />
                <data android:host="m.youtube.com" />
                <data android:host="www.youtube.com" />
                <data android:host="music.youtube.com" />
                <!-- video prefix -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/v/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/embed/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/watch" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/attribution_link" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/shorts/" />
                <!-- channel prefix -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/channel/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/user/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/c/" />
                <!-- playlist prefix -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/playlist" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="youtu.be" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="www.youtube-nocookie.com" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/embed/" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="vnd.youtube" />
                <data android:scheme="vnd.youtube.launch" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Hooktube filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="hooktube.com" />
                <data android:host="*.hooktube.com" />
                <!-- video prefix -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/v/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/embed/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/watch" />
                <!-- channel prefix -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/channel/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/user/" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Invidious filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="tubus.eduvid.org" />
                <data android:host="invidio.us" />
                <data android:host="dev.invidio.us" />
                <data android:host="www.invidio.us" />
                <data android:host="redirect.invidious.io" />
                <data android:host="invidious.snopyta.org" />
                <data android:host="yewtu.be" />
                <data android:host="tube.connect.cafe" />
                <data android:host="invidious.kavin.rocks" />
                <data android:host="invidious-us.kavin.rocks" />
                <data android:host="piped.kavin.rocks" />
                <data android:host="invidious.site" />
                <data android:host="vid.mint.lgbt" />
                <data android:host="invidiou.site" />
                <data android:host="invidious.fdn.fr" />
                <data android:host="invidious.048596.xyz" />
                <data android:host="invidious.zee.li" />
                <data android:host="vid.puffyan.us" />
                <data android:host="ytprivate.com" />
                <data android:host="invidious.namazso.eu" />
                <data android:host="invidious.silkky.cloud" />
                <data android:host="invidious.exonip.de" />
                <data android:host="inv.riverside.rocks" />
                <data android:host="invidious.blamefran.net" />
                <data android:host="invidious.moomoo.me" />
                <data android:host="ytb.trom.tf" />
                <data android:host="yt.cyberhost.uk" />
                <data android:host="y.com.cm" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- y2u.be filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="y2u.be" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Soundcloud filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="soundcloud.com" />
                <data android:host="m.soundcloud.com" />
                <data android:host="www.soundcloud.com" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Share filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- media.ccc.de filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="media.ccc.de" />
                <!-- video prefix -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/v/" />
                <!-- channel prefix-->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/c/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/b/" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- PeerTube filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />

                <data android:host="eduvid.org" />
                <data android:host="framatube.org" />
                <data android:host="media.assassinate-you.net" />
                <data android:host="peertube.co.uk" />
                <data android:host="peertube.cpy.re" />
                <data android:host="peertube.mastodon.host" />
                <data android:host="peertube.fr" />
                <data android:host="tilvids.com" />
                <data android:host="tube.privacytools.io" />
                <data android:host="video.ploud.fr" />
                <data android:host="video.lqdn.fr" />
                <data android:host="skeptikon.fr" />
                <data android:host="media.fsfe.org" />

                <data android:pathPrefix="/videos/" /> <!-- it contains playlists -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/w/" /> <!-- short video URLs -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/w/p/" /> <!-- short playlist URLs -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/accounts/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/a/" /> <!-- short account URLs -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/video-channels/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/c/" /> <!-- short video-channels URLs -->
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Bandcamp filter for tracks, albums and playlists -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH"/>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:host="*.bandcamp.com"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Bandcamp filter for radio -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH"/>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:sspPattern="bandcamp.com/?show=*"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".RouterActivity$FetcherService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <!-- opting out of sending metrics to Google in Android System WebView -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.MetricsOptOut" android:value="true" />
        <!-- see https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/issues/3947 -->
        <!-- Version < 3.0. DeX Mode and Screen Mirroring support -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.keepalive.density" android:value="true"/>
        <!-- Version >= 3.0. DeX Dual Mode support -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.multidisplay.keep_process_alive" android:value="true"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What's the issue you are having with?

Comment: When I try to run the app on the emulator, this message appears Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1996436838.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #459): leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakLauncherActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'

Comment: Looks like you have set the value for exported on launcher Activity.  Have you tried to run again?

Comment: Yes, but I got the same result

Comment: Libraries can also add activities and other elements to the Manifest (will be merged into at compile time). So the problematic element is potentially not included in the AndroidManifest.xml file you see in Android Studio.